# React-Redux Strategies for Refreshing Cognito IdToken

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

I'm using the following combination of packages:

- react
- redux
- react-cognito
- react-router (v4)
- redux-saga

(and I'll disclaim that I'm pretty new with all of these)

Currently I have a `PrivateRoute` component which will check (and refresh if necessary) an expired IdToken on route changes. This works well.

My problem is if the browser is open past token expiry to a PrivateRoute which is polling my API and sending along the IdToken in its 'Authorization' header. The API will start returning 401.

## Options I've Thought of:

#### Act on API Error

I could catch the 401 error and dispatch an action to refresh the token, but

1. if there is any issue refreshing the token I wind up in an infinite loop hammering AWS, so need some logic to catch and prevent this. Perhaps redirect to login route if refresh fails?
2. I then need to add complexity to all my private API calls throughout my app to have this logic, and re-do the requested API call upon successful refresh.

#### Pre-empt API Error

To me it makes more sense to separate API calls and keeping the auth token valid. Considering react-cognito stores the token expiry time in `cognito.user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload.exp`, maybe it is possible to pre-empt the API call and expiry.

How to best do this though? At login a refresh action could be 'scheduled' using setTimeout for (currentTime - expiryTime - someBuffer) seconds in the future.

- I'm assuming (haven't verified) AWS will let you refresh an IdToken before it expires. I don't want to wait until afterwards else some API calls may have already failed.
- are there concerns with using setTimeout with a timeout that may be up to 1 hour long?

Alternatively I could set something up to poll `cognito.user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload.exp` frequently to detect and refresh an almost-expired token?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think in general it's better to be proactive about expiry.  I'm not familiar with cognito- does their API allow you to refresh the idToken before it expires and extend it? Usually you don't want to extend it if the user is inactive, so what I've done in similar situations is refresh it on user actions (clicks, form input, etc.) or else auto logout the user 5 minutes or so before expiry and redirect them to the login screen.

Comment: @brub Cognito does appear to allow refresh before expiry. Why is refreshing during inactivity a bad thing? I figure the user has a refresh token in their local storage they are effectively 'logged in' anyways from a security perspective. Cognito caps the idToken itself at 1hr and many big name sites (albeit, not banks) have logins that persist well beyond 1hr it seems.

Comment: yeah my situation was different, it was a requirement to NOT allow users to stay logged in without activity.  it sounds like you are just talking about typical Oauth2 flow and you want the user to stay logged in until they logout right?  so yeah, ignore my comment about not extending...